Thread::startVirtualThread as Threadfactory
Why does this code lead to a java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException?
newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(Thread::startVirtualThread).scheduleWithFixedDelay(
   () -> System.out.println("Hello, World!"),
   0,
   1,
   TimeUnit.SECONDS
);

The JavaDoc for java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory explicitly states:

An object that creates new threads on demand.

... and Thread::startVirtualThread is a Function<Runnable, Thread> (object) that should do this. Right?
I figure that the intended way is probably Thread.ofVirtual().factory() but I'm still clueless on why the other function doesn't work.

I looked at the relevant source code and it should be the reason for the method parameters. In the Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() method, there is no overload with an input parameter type of Thread, but an overload with an input parameter of type ThreadFactory. Confusingly, though, passing a Thread as a function here is considered syntactically legal

@null ThreadFactory only has a single method so is a functional interface. The Thread::startVirtualThread method reference matches that so can be used there even though it is not actually suitable.

By the way, there is no point to using a virtual thread in a single thread. The point to virtual threads is their number, when many threads are needed.

The JavaDoc for the ThreadFactory newThread method says:

Constructs a new unstarted Thread to run the given runnable.

The key is unstarted which means Thread.getState returns Thread.State.NEW.
Thread.startVirtualThread creates a new virtual thread and immediately starts running it. So the thread state will not be NEW.
The code in ThreadPoolExecutor checks the state of the thread returned by the factory and throws IllegalThreadStateException if it is not NEW.
